# Graph sketching when any of these($ax^2$ / $bx$ / $c$) is missing in $ax^2+bx+c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

> Sketch the graph of the following equations
>
> 1. $2x^2+5x+3$
> 2. $2x^2+5x$
> 3. $5x+3$
> 4. $2x^2+3$

I am a beginner in learning graph sketching. So I have been sketching only '$ax^2+bx+c$' this variation of equations lately. This idea just popped into my head what happens if '$ax^2$ / $bx$ / $c$' is missing from the typical equation which is $ax^2+bx+c$. So could anyone please show me how the curve changes its position when '$ax^2$ / $bx$ / $c$' is absent and solve the above equations for me as well?

Comment: Well: if $ax^2$ is missing you obtain a line, if $bx$ is missing the parabola is symmetric with respect to the $y$ axis and lastly if $c$ is missing the parabola goes through the origin. All of these observation directly follow by setting $a,b,c$ respectively equal to zero in the various formulas.

Comment: When bx is missing, does it mean the curve will never intersect x axis?

Answer (score 1):

If $bx$ or $c$ are missing, then you treat $b$ or $c$ as zero.  If $ax^2$ is missing, then it is no longer a quadratic, it is just a line.

Comment: If c is zero, does that mean the curve doesnt intersect y axis?

Comment: No, it means that the curve intersect $y$-axis at the origin.